# PactDslJsonObject getting resolved to Empty Map {}

Tags: java, pact, pact-java

The object, below, while debugging is being displayed as `{}` instead of `{"types" : ["Ice Cream"] }` as one would expect. Why is this happening.

```
  PactDslJsonObject  resquest = new PactDslJsonObject()         
    .array("type").stringMatcher("\w+","Ice Cream");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. Looks like we must **close** the children of `PactDslJsonObject` or whatever (could be an array as well in that case you will have to close the object withing the array.) is it that we would like to request or respond from aor to a service.

So, in this case it should be,

```
DslPart response = new PactDslJsonObject()         
.array("type").stringMatcher("\w+","Ice Cream").closeArray();
```

Comment: and the regex actually should be (\\w\\s*)+...:)

Comment: Please accept your own answer when you can, and feel free to ask more questions if you're ever stuck.  Cheers.